# python opencv: ingnoring delay in webcam recording

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, webcam-capture

I am using opencv python for video recording. I am getting problem with continuous operation. I have given delay for some events not for the recording. When I run the program, the program is only taking frames after the amount of delay I have gave. Can any one help me to record contentiously even if delay is given in the loop. I am sending you example code. 
Thanks.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fouecc = cv2.VideoWrite_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWrite('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0,(640,480))

while(True):
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      out.write(frame)
      cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      pump_5.dispense(1,1)
      time.sleep(2)
      pump_4.dispense(1,1)
      time.sleep(2)
      if cv2.waitkey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why do you need the delays, though?

Comment: there are many events suppose to take place while video recording like pumping, GUI etc. After some event we need to take delay for getting answers from user.

Comment: maybe with a thread to read from camera and write to a video may work

Comment: @api55 it worked with threading.. thank you for your advise..